# GotFocus Event is not coming after created LostFocus Event in C#

Tags: c#, events, clipboard

I just want to clear the clipboard text if my form `LostFocus`. What I mean is that if a user copies something using his keyboard or mouse, have to clear it on `LostFocus` events, then I need to get my text back if my form receives focus again. How can I achieve this?

```
string sValue = "";
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.LostFocus += new EventHandler(Form1_LostFocus);
    this.GotFocus += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);
}

void Form1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(sValue);
    textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}

void Form1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sValue = textBox1.Text;
    Clipboard.Clear();
}
```

This does not work; the `LostFocus` event is called, but `GotFocus` is not getting called. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string sVal = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Activated += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);
        this.Deactivate += new EventHandler(Form1_LostFocus);

    }

    void Form1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sVal = Clipboard.GetText();
        Clipboard.Clear();
    }

    void Form1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(sVal);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

To give you a quick answer which works, instead of adding the event handlers to the form itself, add them to the `TextBox` control:

```
textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(Form1_LostFocus);
textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);
```

If the form contains any visible controls, it will never trigger the `GotFocus`or the `LostFocus` events.

But the **recommended** way to handle this behavior at the form level is to use:

```
this.Deactivate += new EventHandler(Form1_LostFocus);
this.Activated += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);
```

or

```
textBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(Form1_LostFocus);
textBox1.Enter += new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);
```

Microsoft says:

1. For the [Control.GotFocus Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx)

   > **The GotFocus and LostFocus events are low-level focus events that are
   >   tied to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS Windows messages. Typically,
   >   the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when updating UICues
   >   or when writing custom controls. Instead the Enter and Leave events
   >   should be used for all controls except the Form class, which uses the
   >   Activated and Deactivate events.**
2. For the [Form.Activated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx)

   > When the application is active and has multiple forms, the active form
   >   is the form with the input focus. A form that is not visible cannot be
   >   the active form. The simplest way to activate a visible form is to
   >   click it or use an appropriate keyboard combination.
3. For the [Control.Enter Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx)

   > The Enter and Leave events are suppressed by the Form class. The
   >   equivalent events in the Form class are the Activated and Deactivate
   >   events.